# Schedule Library and Multi Define Functions in Python

Tags: python, schedule

I wanna combine these two codes:

```py
import schedule 

import time 

def good_luck(): 

    print("Good Luck for Test") 

schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(good_luck)

while True: 

    schedule.run_pending() 

    time.sleep(1)
```

and

```py
def myCommand():

    command = input('input: ')

    return command

def assistant(command):

    if command == '1':

        print('is it one')

    else:

        print('is not one')    

while True:

    assistant(myCommand())
```

I got errors in half of my experiments, in the other half the first code never worked.

Comment: Please note your intended outcome by editing your question to add additional information. As written, it is difficult to determine what you are trying to achieve given that there are many ways to 'combine' your two code samples.

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear how you want to combine these two listings. the easiest way is to execute both functions in the same loop, however this solution might not work for your problem.

```
import schedule


def good_luck():
    print("Good Luck for Test")


def myCommand():
    command = input("input: ")
    return command


def assistant(command):
    if command == "1":
        print("is it one")
    else:
        print("is not one")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(good_luck)

    while True:
        assistant(myCommand())
        schedule.run_pending()
```

then you could get the following output

```
input: 1
is it one
input: 2
is not one
Good Luck for Test
```